# Using conan in Bazel for linux but not for windows

Tags: bazel, conan, bazel-rules

I have a system that is built using `Bazel` and is using `OpenCV` as a 3rd party package.

When building on Linux I want to use a prebuilt package using `conan`, and when using Windows I want to use a locally compiled version, and not use conan.

What I have at the moment is in my `WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@//conan:dependencies.bzl", "load_conan_dependencies")
load_conan_dependencies()

new_local_repository(
    name = "windows_opencv",
    build_file = "@//third_party:opencv_windows.BUILD",
    path = "C:\\opencv\\build",
)
```

and the `conanfile.txt` looks like this:

```
[requires]
OpenCV/3.4.13@company/dev

[generators]
BazelDeps
BazelToolchain
```

This works well for the Linux part, but because I don't have the `OpenCV/3.4.13@company/dev` package for Windows, I can't use `conan install` and not rules are generated, so trying to build on Windows causes this error:

```
ERROR: error loading package '': Label '//conan:dependencies.bzl' is invalid because 'conan' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '//:conan/dependencies.bzl'?
```

The way I currently see this is I have 2 options:

- Have 2 `conanfile.txt`, 1 which contains the `OpenCV` package and another empty only with the generators, to create the necessary conan files so it would pass the `load` call
- Create an empty `OpenCV` conan package and again just insall it so the `load` call would pass

Both options seems to me like bad hacks and workarounds, but I'm not familiar enough with `Bazel` to know if there's a better option.

What I would like to be able to do is only load the conan dependencies rule for Linux and ignore it on Windows.

Currently the selection between Linux & Windows OpenCV is done using alias:

```
alias(
    name = "opencv_binary",
    actual = select({
        "//mediapipe:windows": "@windows_opencv//:opencv",
        "//conditions:default": "@opencv//:opencv",
    }),
)
```

where `@opencv//:opencv` is the conan pacakge

Comment: Why not using a ``conanfile.py`` with a ``requirements()`` method, that you can put any ``if ...`` (like conditioning on Windows) to do a ``self.requires("opencv...")``? You can also use the ``generate()`` method for adding extra logic, as automating what files are prepared before the build. A ``conanfile.py`` can be used for ``conan install .`` in the same way, but it is more powerful, and it doesn't mean that you are creating a package, it is just for consuming.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the `conanfile.py` until this morning, and I actually implemented something similar to what you just said in our `cmake` project a few hours ago. so yeah, it sounds like a great idea that would probably work. Thanks!